# Selenium webdriver-java.lang.NullPointerException at PageFactory.Add.main(Add.java:21)

Tags: selenium, webdriver

```
package PageFactory;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;


    public class Add{
        public static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main (String args[]){
        try
        {
        WebElement popup=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/a[1]"));
        WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='name']"));
        WebElement submit=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit']"));
        WebElementproceed=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/a[2]"));


            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();

            driver.navigate().to("testurl");    
            popup.click();  
            String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
            ArrayList<String> newTab = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
            newTab.remove(oldTab);
            driver.switchTo().window(newTab.get(0));
            name.sendKeys("neha");
            submit.click();
            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(oldTab);
            proceed.click();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        }



    }
```

I am trying on selenium webdriver

I tried a lot to resolve this but no success
java 1.8
chrome 67
webdriver
selenium server standalone-3.12.0.jar

tried with tesng then also getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the driver initialization, you have find the element and hence null pointer exception is throwing .
Please change the code as below by moving the driver initialization part above the webelement

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();

        WebElement popup=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/a[1]"));
        WebElement name=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='name']"));
        WebElement submit=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='submit']"));
        WebElementproceed=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/a[2]"));
```